# Преобразование входных данных в многомерный массив

Tags: python, массивы, list, многомерные-списки

Можно ли как-нибудь по-простому строку наподобие

```
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
```

Преобразовать в трехмерный массив без кучи вложенных циклов?
Вопрос стоит так: каким образом можно строку преобразовать в многомерный массив, зная его (массива) размерность (в примере размерность 2х2х2).

Comment: Трёхмерный? Двухмерный я понимаю, это строки и столбцы, а как брать трёхмерный по вашему мнению? Я не понимаю.

Comment: Так если размерность изначально известна, к примеру в данном случае (в примере) `2х2х2`. Если вложенными циклами это делать, то `for x in... for y in... for z in... array.append(element)`

Comment: Вопрос в том, как нужно интрепретировать данные в многомерный массив. От этого будет понятнее, где какое число будет находиться

Comment: Вот в этом и вопрос, как это сделать по-красивше, без кучи вложенных циклов

Comment: В данный момент, такое чувство, что будет достаточно массив с несколькими вложениями. Но, так как я не до конца разобрался, сделаю ответ общим и опубликую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без кучи вложенных циклов. Правда рекурсивное.

```
def fold(shape, seq):
    it = iter(seq)

    def fold(i):
        if i == len(shape):
            return next(it)
        return [fold(i + 1) for _ in range(shape[i])]

    return fold(0)


print(fold((2, 3, 4), range(1, 1 + 2 * 3 * 4)))
```

> ```
> [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]], [[13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24]]]
> ```

Что можно отформатировать в

> ```
> [
>     [
>         [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
>         [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
>         [ 9, 10, 11, 12]
>     ], [
>         [13, 14, 15, 16],
>         [17, 18, 19, 20],
>         [21, 22, 23, 24]
>     ]
> ]
> ```

Чтение из строки:

```
data = '''
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
'''
print(fold((2, 2, 2), map(int, data.split())))
```

> ```
> [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]
> ```

Чтение из входного потока:

```
def ints():
    while True:
        yield from map(int, input().split())


print(fold((2, 2, 2), ints()))
```

> ```
> $ python fold.py
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> 1 1
> [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Да в общем-то ничего сложного, если использовать `Numpy` для решейпа:

```py
import numpy as np

data_str = """
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
"""

shape = (2, 2, 2)

data = list(map(int, (x for line in data_str.split('\n') for x in line.split())))
arr = np.array(data).reshape(shape)
print(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
[[[1 1]
  [1 1]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 1]]]
```

Comment: Два сплита не нужны. Правого достаточно. Решение будет проще.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np


s  = """1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1"""

arr = np.fromiter(s.replace("\n", " ").split(), dtype=np.int32)
arr = arr.reshape((2, 2, 2))

print(arr)
```